# Scrolling in vim autocomplete box with jk movement keys

Tags: vim, autocomplete

In vim you can start typing a word, hit ctrl-n, and a box will popup with suggested completions. I don't like having to move my hands away to the arrow keys to scroll through this list. Is there some way I can use the jk keys to scroll down/up instead?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
inoremap <expr> j ((pumvisible())?("\<C-n>"):("j"))
inoremap <expr> k ((pumvisible())?("\<C-p>"):("k"))
```

Comment: Very interesting question and solution : every time there is a popup I automatically use j and k without a second thought..

Comment: NB: you will loose the possibility to type on-the-fly part of the text (when it contains `j` or `k`.)

Comment: is it possible to make it alt+j/k?

Comment: you can replace j/k by <down>/<up>

Comment: Can you explain these mappings?

Comment: @MatthewWoo if `pumvisible` is true, run Ctrl+N, which is the default way to do "next" in the autocomplete box, otherwise, just input "j", same for "k". I assume `pumvisible` returns true of the autocomplete box is open.

Comment: Agh! This is such a cool mapping, but it means you lose the use of jk, kj, as escape mappings, even with jdhao's `better-escape` plugin.

Answer (score 49):

I know the question is asking to use the J and K keys but you can also avoid using the arrow keys another way.

After hitting ctrl+n to get the autocomplete popup, you can navigate the list with ctrl+n and ctrl+p.

Comment: This is still the best option but it occasionally breaks when a plugin binds the keymap. For example the database tools plugin takes ctrl+n. Delete these and it'll work fine again. To find them go to `settings > keymap > keyboard icon (find actions by shortcut)` and enter ctrl+n or ctrl+p.

Answer (score 2):

```
inoremap <expr> <down> ((pumvisible())?("\<C-n>"):("\<down>"))
inoremap <expr> <up> ((pumvisible())?("\<C-p>"):("\<up>"))
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. However j and k instead of <down> and <up> work fine