# Faster way to jump to specific autocomplete option

Tags: vim, autocomplete

Say somewhere in my Vim buffer that I have the following:

```
function foo() {
    return 'funday, funky, funnel cake';
}
```

Now I want to create a new function below this..

I start typing `fun` and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> to bring up my autocomplete menu.
In that menu, I get (in this hypothetical order):

```
funday
funnel
function
funky
```

Normally, I would <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd> twice to highlight `function`, which isn't a big deal.. but what if I have 20 results and I want to get to the 10th result *really fast*.

Is there any known way (or plugin) to quickly jump to specific values in a Vim autocomplete menu?

---

**Update:**
Using a hack, I found a way to jump by X autocomplete options:

```
" j/k for up and down in autocomplete menu
inoremap <expr> j ((pumvisible())?("\<C-n>"):("j"))
inoremap <expr> k ((pumvisible())?("\<C-p>"):("k"))

" Hack to jump down x positions
inoremap <expr> 2 ((pumvisible())?("\<C-n><C-n>"):("2"))
inoremap <expr> 3 ((pumvisible())?("\<C-n><C-n><C-n>"):("3"))
inoremap <expr> 4 ((pumvisible())?("\<C-n><C-n><C-n><C-n>"):("4"))
```

However, my vimscript is gross. Anyone got a better way to do this?

Comment: found this method of setting up j and k to work when autocomplete is showing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739901/scrolling-in-vim-autocomplete-box-with-jk-movement-keys/4740069#4740069 still not as efficient as I would like it to be.

Comment: don't think so, read about it by doing a `:help i_CTRL-N`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you are interested in [neocomplcache](https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplcache) plugin

Answer (score 4):

As far as quickly jumping to a specific autocomplete, I have the following workflow.

In my .vimrc:

```c
set completeopt=longest,menuone
```

The `longest` option prevents the first match from being automatically selected. This means Vim will wait for you to finish typing the rest of the word, and the completion popup will automatically narrow as you type more characters of the word.

In your example, you would type `fun`, hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>, to bring up your autocomplete menu. At this point, you would still see:

```
funday
funnel
function
funky
```

...but now the first choice (funday) would no longer be automatically chosen. You could then type "c", which would narrow the list to:

```
function
```

This is the fastest way that I know of, using pure Vim, anyway. I tend to like pure Vim solutions, myself. :)

**EDIT:** Realized that I forgot to include "menuone" at the end of the line in my `.vimrc` file. This causes Vim to show the autocomplete menu, even if there was only one match. You would need either "menuone" or "menu" in the `set completeopt` line in order to actually see the popup with completions.

Comment: To avoid having to retype the beginning of the string that I had already started before activating autocomplete, I found I had to add `noinsert`, i.e., the `set` command is now: `set completeopt=longest,menuone,noinsert`.