# Vim autocomplete key bindings for closing & choosing

Tags: vim

I have `j`/`k` set to scroll in the autocomplete box as posted in this question: [Scrolling in vim autocomplete box with jk movement keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739901/scrolling-in-vim-autocomplete-box-with-jk-movement-keys)

Now I want to map `h` to close the box without completion, and `l` to close with completion. Both should stay in insert mode. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
inoremap <expr> h ((pumvisible())?("\<C-e>"):("h"))        
inoremap <expr> l ((pumvisible())?("\<C-y>"):("l"))
```