# Cycle through autocomplete suggestions without arrows

Tags: intellij-idea, autocomplete

I'm really impressed with the autocomplete feature of the IntelliJ IDE so far.

What I'd like to do, is cycle through the autocomplete suggestions I get when hitting <kbd>Ctrl + Space</kbd> without using the arrow keys (<kbd>↑</kbd>, <kbd>↓</kbd>).

The reason for this is that I prefer to keep my fingers on the home row (I'm using [IntelliJ's Vim emulator](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/164?pr=idea) additionally).

For example, how would I select `sortThis` instead of `sorted` without using the arrow keys or the mouse?

[image: autocompletion example]

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Peter Gromov's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26323601/cycle-through-autocomplete-suggestions-without-arrows/26324056#26324056) brought me to a satisfying solution:

In IntelliJ's settings, for `Keymap → Editor Actions → Down` I set a custom shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl + J</kbd>.

This way I can cycle forward through the suggestions.

[image: down_shortcut]

Setting a shortcut for `Down with Selection` or `Scroll Line Down` in the IdeaVim-specific shortcuts did not affect the selection of autocomplete suggestions though.

Comment: So that means when you press Ctrl-J when there is no suggestion popup, you go down a row.

Comment: Yes, @AntonK. But that might be because I have IntelliJ's Vim plugin installed.

Answer (score 14):

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9713306/2370679) led me to discover that <kbd>Ctrl+n</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+p</kbd> allow navigation of the auto-complete options without having to modify any settings.

Comment: Personally I think one of the major benefits to using vim is that it works in so many places. So I like this solution that uses the inbuilt vim features.

Answer (score 5):

For macOS the IDE will give a hint that "`^↑` and `^↓` will move caret up and down in the editor". These clearly do not work.

There are a few extra steps that are needed after following @matthias-braun's solution.

Here is the full list of step that I use:

1. Go to `Preferences -> Keymap`
2. Expand `Editor Actions` (not `Plug-ins -> IdeaVim`)
3. Select `Down`
4. Click the pencil icon or right-click
5. Select `Add Keyboard Shortcut`
6. Press the shortcut (I use `^N`)*
7. Repeat for 3-6 for `Up` (I use `^P`)
8. Click `Ok`**
9. Go to `Preferences -> Other Settings -> Vim Emulation`
10. In the drop-down under the `Handler` column for the row containing `Down`, select `Vim`***
11. Do the same thing for `Up`

* If you are warned about the key binding already existing then remove it. You can always reset back to the defaults by clicking the little cog icon up the very top to the right of the drop-down menu.

** The `Vim Emulation` doesn't seem to be populated correctly until you reopen the `Preferences`.

*** I'm not sure why the `Handler` should be `Vim`. This seems backwards to me but it works.

Comment: Interesting! On Windows 10, `Ctrl+N` is set to `New Folder...` and `Ctrl+P`is set to `Show/Hide path text`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're able to scroll up/down in editor with some IdeaVIM-specific shortcuts, they should also work in the completion list.

In this particular case, I'd just type another "t" so that "sortThis" becomes selected (and the only) variant.

Comment: Thanks. This led me to the solution I describe in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have done the same thing with mapping the arrows but in a more logical way:
I mapped them that when I press 'Alt' 'J' is left, 'L' is right, 'I' is up, and 'k' is down. that way I can have easy access to the arrows while my fingers are on the home row and I don't need to move them nearly as much...

I'm posting it just so people who search it on google can have that idea.