# select autocomplete suggestions without arrows in Jupyter and its vim extension

Tags: vim, jupyter-notebook

I am using Jupyter notebook and the vim extension for Python coding. I want to select the autocomplete suggestions without using arrow keys. I found [Cycle through autocomplete suggestions without arrows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26323601/cycle-through-autocomplete-suggestions-without-arrows), but the keyboard shortcuts for scroll down/up (ctrl-E, ctrl-Y) in Jupyter notebook don't work for cycling the suggestions. Anyone knows how to do it in jupyter with vim extension?

Comment: Do CTRL-P (down) and CTRL-N (up) work? Those are the usual Vim keys while navigating a complete menu... (See [`:help ins-completion-menu`](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#ins-completion-menu).)

Comment: CTRL-N opens a new web page in chrome :-(. CTRL-P does nothing. But thank you, you solved another question I had in vscode; now I can use CTRL-P and N to select suggestions without using arrows in vscode :-)

Comment: (this question is old but) Which plugin are you using exactly? If it's https://github.com/lambdalisue/jupyter-vim-binding then it's mentioned in the readme and you can bind it to different keys